# Discussion - Integrating Accelerometer data to Position data from Frequency domain FFT

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, fourier-transform, frequency

I came across one blog who suggested to convert from accelerometer data to position data from frequency domain. Here are the steps that the original individual suggested:

> 1. Remove the mean from the accel. data
> 2. Take the Fourier transform (FFT) of the accel. data.
> 3. Convert the transformed accel. data to displacement data by dividing each element by -omega^2, where omega is the frequency band.
> 4. Now take the inverse FFT to get back to the time-domain and scale your result.

I am wondering if anyone have ever used this method before, and may I know your algorithm? I am not particularly sure on what does it means by Step 3 - frequency band?

p.s. I hope this question is relevant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that acceleration is the second derivative of displacement. So to get the displacement, one should integrate acceleration twice. To do this, one way is to numerically integrate. A more interesting approach is to use the *time-integration* property of the Fourier transform:
$$\mathcal{F}\left(\int_{-\infty}^t x(\tau)d\tau\right)=\frac{X(j\omega)}{j\omega}$$
Note that we require $X(0)=0$. So division by $-\omega^2$ means twice integration in time.
Assuming the sampling frequency is `fs` and `a` is accel. data, you can use something similar to the following code:

```
 l = length(a); % assume l even 
 w = 2*pi*fs/l*(-l/2:l/2-1);
 A = fftshift(fft(a));
 D = A./-w.^2;
 d = ifft(ifftshift(D),'symmetric');
```